# Xpath Unable to locate path

Tags: java, xpath

```
    <input class="btn btn-danger confirm" value="Send this!" type="submit">
```

This input is inside a modal div and is not displayed(display:none) and only displays (display:block) when I click the trigger for the modal. 
The problem is that the modal becomes visible but it can't find the input element.

I tried this

```
    modal.click(); //triggers modal

    WebElement send1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Send this!']"));
    send1.click();
```

also

```
    modal.click(); //triggers modal

    WebElement send1 = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@class='confirm']"));
    send1.click();
```

Does not work. Yields unable to locate xpath.

Answer (score 0):

Currently you try to access the input element the very moment the modal is getting generated but your requested input element is not yet available. Wait until your modal is visible and then try to access your input field should yield the expected result (or wait until the input element is in DOM instead of clickable).